# Comparing different columns in SQL for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

after some transformation I have a result from a cross join (from table a and b) where I want to do some analysis on. The table for this looks like this:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+
| id  | 10_1 | 10_2 | 11_1 | 11_2 | id  | 10_1 | 10_2 | 11_1 | 11_2 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+
| 111 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 | 222 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
| 111 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 | 333 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 111 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 | 444 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
| 112 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 | 222 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

The ids in the first column are different from the ids in the sixth column.
In a row are always two different IDs that are matched with each other. The other columns always have either 0 or 1 as a value.

I am now trying to find out how many values(meaning both have "1" in 10_1, 10_2 etc) two IDs have on average in common, but I don't really know how to do so.

I was trying something like this as a start:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a.10_1 = 1 AND b.10_1 = 1 then 1 end)
```

But this would obviously only count how often two ids have 10_1 in common. I could make something like this for example for different columns:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (a.10_1 = 1 AND b.10_1 = 1) 
OR (a.10_2 = 1 AND b.10_1 = 1) OR [...] then 1 end)
```

To count in general how often two IDs have one thing in common, but this would of course also count if they have two or more things in common. Plus, I would also like to know how often two IDS have two things, three things etc in common.

One "problem" in my case is also that I have like ~30 columns I want to look at, so I can hardly write down for each case every possible combination.

Does anyone know how I can approach my problem in a better way?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
A possible result could look like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
| in_common |  count  |
+-----------+---------+
|         0 |     100 |
|         1 |     500 |
|         2 |    1500 |
|         3 |    5000 |
|         4 |    3000 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to get.  Let me add that the `CROSS JOIN` results doesn't seem like it helps with your goal.  Why not delete this question.  Ask another question with your actual data and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added a possible result. The reason why I did the cross join before is the following: I have two subsets (like male and female) that I want to match with each other based on some criteria - and I do so with the cross join and some where clauses. After this I get interim result as shown above, where I want to know how many values males and females, that are match together, have on average in common.

Comment: What do your data look like before transformation?  The solution would be more straightforward if your data table had two columns, one for the id and one for the code (10_1, 10_2, etc.)

Comment: Before transformation data looks similar to the table shown above. One column with an id, around 30-40 columns for each code(10_1 etc), and a couple of other columns, like age, gender etc. From the latter I am using some columns (like gender, age) for the matching. The two subsets of male and females are both from this table.

Answer (score 0):

With the codes as column names, you're going to have to write some code that explicitly references each column name.  To keep that to a minimum, you could write those references in a single union statement that normalizes the data, such as:

```
select id, '10_1' where "10_1" = 1
union
select id, '10_2' where "10_2" = 1
union
select id, '11_1' where "11_1" = 1
union
select id, '11_2' where "11_2" = 1;
```

This needs to be modified to include whatever additional columns you need to link up different IDs.  For the purpose of this illustration, I assume the following data model

```
create table p (
    id integer not null primary key,
    sex character(1) not null,
    age integer not null
    );

create table t1 (
    id integer not null,
    code character varying(4) not null,
    constraint pk_t1 primary key (id, code)
    );
```

Though your data evidently does not currently resemble this structure, normalizing your data into a form like this would allow you to apply the following solution to summarize your data in the desired form.

```
select
    in_common,
    count(*) as count
from (
    select
        count(*) as in_common
    from (
        select
        a.id as a_id, a.code,
        b.id as b_id, b.code
        from
        (select p.*, t1.code
            from p left join t1 on p.id=t1.id
            ) as a
        inner join (select p.*, t1.code
            from p left join t1 on p.id=t1.id
            ) as b on b.sex <> a.sex and b.age between a.age-10 and a.age+10
        where
        a.id < b.id
        and a.code = b.code
        ) as c
    group by
        a_id, b_id
    ) as summ
group by
    in_common;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution requires first to take one step back from the cross-join table, as the identical column names are super annoying. Instead, we take the `id`s from the two tables and put them in a temporary table. The following query gets the result wanted in the question. It assumes `table_a` and `table_b` from the question are the same and called `tbl`, but this assumption is not needed and `tbl` can be replaced by `table_a` and `table_b` in the two sub-SELECT queries. It looks complicated and uses the JSON trick to flatten the columns, but it works here:

```
WITH idtable AS (
SELECT a.id as id_1, b.id as id_2 FROM
   -- put cross join of table a and table b here
)
SELECT in_common,
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT idtable.*,
          sum(CASE
                  WHEN meltedR.value::text=meltedL.value::text THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
              END) AS in_common
   FROM idtable
   JOIN
     (SELECT tbl.id,
             b.*
      FROM tbl,                         -- change here to table_a
           json_each(row_to_json(tbl)) b          -- and here too
      WHERE KEY<>'id' ) meltedL ON (idtable.id_1 = meltedL.id)
   JOIN
     (SELECT tbl.id,
             b.*
      FROM tbl,                         -- change here to table_b
           json_each(row_to_json(tbl)) b          -- and here too
      WHERE KEY<>'id' ) meltedR ON (idtable.id_2 = meltedR.id
                                    AND meltedL.key = meltedR.key)
   GROUP BY idtable.id_1,
            idtable.id_2) tt
GROUP BY in_common ORDER BY in_common;
```

The output here looks like this:

```
 in_common | count 
-----------+-------
         2 |     2
         3 |     1
         4 |     1
(3 rows)
```